# Unable to locate ros-indigo on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros, wheezy, raspberrypi, raspbian, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm trying ROS indigo on a raspberry pi with wheezy raspbian as OS. Now i'm trying to install the simulator requested in [This link](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes) but it can't find it. I also tried looking for ros-indigo-* but obtained nothing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197051/unable-to-locate-ros-indigo-on-a-raspberry-pi/) by [GPaolo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/20745/gpaolo93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all packages are available for raspberry pi. There are installation instructions for groovy. http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian

However, most of the more recent efforts for ARM support have been focused on more standard armhf processors.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0